# Using SAS to check if columns have specified characteristics

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a dataset that looks like the one below.  each row is a different observation that has anywhere from 1 to x values (in this case x=3).  I want to create a dataset that contains the original info, but four additional columns (for the four values of Bin present in the dataset).  The value of the column freq_Bin_1 will be a 1 if there are any 1's present in that row, else missing. The column freq_Bin_2 will be a 1 if there are any 2's present, etc.

Both the number of Bins and the number of columns in the original dataset may vary.

```
data have;
    input Bin_1 Bin_2 Bin_3;
cards;
1 . .
3 . .
1 1 .
3 2 1
3 4 .
;
run;
```

Here is my desired output:

```
data want_this;
    input Bin_1 Bin_2 Bin_3 freq_Bin_1 freq_Bin_2 freq_Bin_3 freq_Bin_4;
cards;
1 . . 1 . . .
3 . . . . 1 .
1 1 . 1 . . .
3 2 1 1 1 1 .
3 4 . . . 1 1
;
run;
```

I have an array solution that I think is pretty close, but I can't quite get it.  I am also open to other methods.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array Bins {&max_freq.} Bin:; 
    array freq_Bin {&num_bin.} freq_Bin_1-freq_Bin_&num_bin.;
    do j=1 to dim(Bins);
        freq_Bin(j)=.;
    end;
    do k=1 to dim(freq_Bin);
        if Bins(k)=1 then freq_Bin(1)=1;
        else if Bins(k)=2 then freq_Bin(2)=1;
        else if Bins(k)=3 then freq_Bin(3)=1;
        else if Bins(k)=4 then freq_Bin(4)=1;
    end;
    drop j k;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
data want;
    set have;
    array Bins{*} Bin:; 
    array freq_Bin{4};
    do k=1 to dim(Bins);
        if Bins(k) ne . then freq_Bin(Bins(k))=1;
    end;
    drop k;
run;
```

I tweaked your code somewhat, but really the only problem was that you need to check that `Bins(k)` isn't missing before trying to use it to index an array. Also, there's no need to initialize the values to missing as that's the default.